# Handling multiple Fact Tables with different Aggregation

Tags: powerbi, dax, multiple-tables, datamodel, fact-table

I have 2 dim and 2 fact tables with the following model:
[image: Data Model]

So the problem I get is in vizulising both fact values in one Visual without grouping (don't want to MAX or SUM the BookingDate or costs).

Here the Name "abc" should get 30 sales and three different costs and the other Names ("def" and "ghi") should get 30 and 15 sales and no costs (tables on the right). But as you can see the Visual showing all the values of both fact tables without any relationship (table in the middle):
[image: Visuals]

I would expect this:
[image: Expected Result]

Does somebody has any Idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: will you be able to share the PBIX file? by the look of it booking date and salesSum measure has some conflicts. Make fact2 and dim2 relationship bidirectional.

Comment: There's no filter flow between fact2 and fact1 so putting the detail rows from both tables on a visual causes a cross-join.